# Use jasmine to expect that a function has been assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

Take the following example es6 class:

```
export default class sellerController {
    saveOrUpdate(){
        return this.id ? this.updateSettings.bind(this) : this.saveNewSettings.bind(this);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a unit test for that saveOrUpdateMethod.

```
it("Should select between save or update if id is or isn't set", function() {

      var saveOrUpdate = SellerDetailsCtrl.saveOrUpdate();
      expect(saveOrUpdate).toEqual(SellerDetailsCtrl.updateSettings.bind(SellerDetailsCtrl))
    });
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Error is

> Expected Function to equal Function.

Is it even possible to do that? Validate that i have assigned a specific function, bound, to a variable?

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `bind` always returns new anonymous function, you can try to compare by functions body:

```
var saveOrUpdate = SellerDetailsCtrl.saveOrUpdate();
expect(saveOrUpdate.toString()).toEqual(SellerDetailsCtrl.updateSettings.bind(SellerDetailsCtrl).toString())
```

However, this will only ensure that a bound function is returned, without understanding which function is bound. So it provides no way to checking for *specific* bound function.

A better approach would be to use `spy`:

```
spyOn(SellerDetailsCtrl.updateSettings).and.callFake(function() {
    return 'updateSettings';
})

var saveOrUpdate = SellerDetailsCtrl.saveOrUpdate();
expect(saveOrUpdate()).toEqual('updateSettings');
```

Another alternative is to override native `bind` for the test and then resetting it back to native:

```
var native = Function.prototype.bind;

Function.prototype.bind = (function () {
    var originalBind = Function.prototype.bind;
    return function (obj) {
        var bound = originalBind.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        bound.original = this;

        return bound;
    };
}());

var saveOrUpdate = SellerDetailsCtrl.saveOrUpdate();
expect(saveOrUpdate.original).toEqual(SellerDetailsCtrl.updateSettings);

Function.prototype.bind = native;
```